# Angular 2 using custom pipe

Tags: angular

I created a new pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'reverse'
})
export class ReversePipe {
  transform(arr) {
    var copy = arr.slice();
    return copy.reverse();
  }
}
```

Imported it in my component:

```
import { ReversePipe } from '../reverse.pipe';
```

Also here:

```
pipes: [ReversePipe]
```

but when I run my app I get

```
The pipe 'reverse' could not be found
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the module that you intend to use the pipe

`import { ReversePipe } from '../reverse.pipe';`

And then in the declarations

```
NgModule({
 declarations: [
        <...>,
        ReversePipe
    ]
```

This makes the name available for template compilation.